# connect nativescripte vue app to localhost server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have Laravel app as server and i'm trying to connect it to native script vue app on emulator (same machine).

Whene i use an external api, it work just fine but when using my api it wont connect :

```
axios({ method: "GET", "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts" }) .then(result => { this.posts = result.data ; }, error => { console.error(error); });
```

and also

```
axios({ method: "GET", "url": "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/posts" }) .then(result => { this.posts = result.data ; }, error => { console.error(error); })
```